# No results for a child relationship tag after upgrading to 2.7.3

Tags: ee2, relationships, 2.7.3

I have a relationship field in a page with the name `pro_related_program`.  Before the update from 2.5.5 to 2.7.3 this code snippet (as part of a larger template that loads a single channel entry):

```
{related_entries id="pro_related_program"}
 <div id="midLeftInset">            
<p>This session is part of a larger series.  For more information see <a href="{title_permalink="programs/catalogue"}" title="TDLC: {title}">{title}</a></p>
</div>{/related_entries}
```

would result in this html for a specific page on my website:

```
<div id="midLeftInset">            
<p>This session is part of a larger series.  For more information see <a href="https://www.jointokyo.org/en/programs/catalogue/DRM2011" title="TDLC: Disaster Risk Management in East Asia and the Pacific - 2011 Series">Disaster Risk Management in East Asia and the Pacific - 2011 Series</a></p>
</div>
```

the upgrade modified the code template snippet to:

```
{pro_related_program}
 <div id="midLeftInset">            
<p>This session is part of a larger series.  For more information see <a href="{pro_related_program:title_permalink="programs/catalogue"}" title="TDLC: {pro_related_program:title}">{pro_related_program:title}</a></p>
</div>{/pro_related_program}
```

which gives me back nothing.  If I add a `no_results` clause in there it gives me the contents of the `no_results` clause.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this?  What I coulddo to debug it?

Comment: Does the child entry have a status other than "open"? A future entry date? An expiration date in the past? All these would require further parameters to be set on the `pro_related_program` tag, much like a `channel:entries` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Derek Hogue has suggested and from my own experience, I think this is likely an issue of a missed status parameter in the relationship tag pair. Also it also bears mentioning that the status parameter in relationship tag pairs at least up until the current EE version of 2.8.1 **is case sensitive**, which is different from the channel:entries status parameter behavior which is **not** case sensitive.

To test this, you could try something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="your_channel" status="not closed"}

{pro_related_program status="not closed"}
{pro_related_program:title}
{/pro_related_program}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: The status thing was it.  Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and I've discovered a strange behavior. Having the relationship fields without the wrapping is working.

This seemingly proper code provides nothing:

```
{brief channel="projects" status="Open|Closed"} 
    {brief:title}
    {brief:entry_id}
{/brief}
```

While this one without the wrapping tag pair gives me what I need:

```
{brief:title}
{brief:entry_id}
```

Was this a bug?

Comment: try status="open|closed" instead of status="Open|Closed"